# products v1.2 api returns both pool and airport pool. How to decide which one is applicable for user

Tags: uber-api

Upon calling the products api between 2 places, the product list contains pool, pool airport both. Even though the drop location is no where near airport. How do we decide which one to show the user
Similarly in some cases we get both uber go, go intercity in the response.